# Why does my attempt at parallelization not work?

Tags: parallelization

I want to run some function with different parameters, parallel on 4 cores (i5).
When I run it without using `Parallelize`, processor has ~25% utilization.
It's a little time consuming (a couple of minutes), so I tried run it 4x with different parameters on each core.

I tried: `Parallelize[{f[a1,b1,c1],f[a2,b2,c2],f[a3,b3,c3],f[a4,b4,c4]}]` (also with different methods like: "FinestGrained"/"CoarsestGrained"/"EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 1) and still, total utilization of cpu is 30% top).

1. Each variant is processed within a few minutes, at least 4 minutes.
2. In Parallel Kernel Status window all 4 kernels have status *busy*, after the start of the calculation.
   I used Parallelize earlier and it worked just fine (~100% utilization).

So, what is the reason?

My configuration: 
Mathematica 9.0.0/Win8 x64/i5 2500k, 4GB RAM

Comment: There could be several reasons.  Can you check the CPU utilization of each subkernel process separately with a task monitor, as well as that of the main process, and tell us what you found?

Comment: A few things will help: knowing your OS and version of Mathematica. Full specs on the machine (total cores, Mma V9 has native support for 6 cores in parallel).  While it sounds like you've got all of this running on a single machine, let us know if you want to do this across a network.  Check that you don't have other processes running to compete for usage of the 4 cores.

Comment: Might help a lot if we knew how your function `f` was defined.

Comment: It sounds like some function is unexpectedly being evaluated in the main kernel. The test Szabolcs mentioned will show you if this is the case; you can also put "Print[$KernelID]" in various places in your code to verify that functions are being executed in parallel. Use of SetSharedFunction (or possibly SetSharedVariable) will cause functions (or variables, respectively) to be evaluated in the main kernel. If your function uses a symbol which is not in the current context (e.g. from a package), and you forget to invoke DistributeDefinitions,

Comment: the symbol will be returned from the parallel kernel unevaluated, at which point the main kernel will evaluate it.

Comment: If providing `f` is not feasible, you could reword the problem to ask for a list of the most common causes of utilization failure, in the hope of eliciting more answers.

Comment: You might isolate the problem by running a very simple function (or maybe PlatoManiac's) to see if  you can get something to work.

Comment: If you want to know the real reason, you will have to provide a real test case. As it is, people are having to guess, because not enough information has been supplied from which to draw any definitive conclusions. Although it would be entirely appropriate to close this question as "not constructive" as it stands, I hope you can make it more specific so that this won't be necessary.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.
Generally, function generates some graph (output). It uses some custom functions i.e. Minimum Spanning Tree to generate graph. I will not post that code, because it is a lot of code + files with data. 
Every function f is independent in it's evaluation. Gets data from a file, processes it and gives a graph as an output.

Comment: @Tobias Hagge
Thanks. I will check that!

Comment: @Jagra It is not really correct to say that Mma 9 has support for 6 cores ...  You can launch as many parallel processes as your license allows, which may vary.   This, or anything related to the hardware configuration, is likely not the cause of the problem.  What would help is a test case, as Oleksandr mentioned, and readings of how much CPU each subkernel as well as the main kernel use.  In an extreme situation it may even happen that simply transferring back the results from one subkernel is keeping the main kernel busy and the other subkernels have to wait (has happened to me).

Comment: @crobartie if your functions are really independent of each other then you have an "embarrassingly parallel" problem and trivially achieve perfect parallelization. However, I expect you are loading each of the files from the same disk/network and using the same front end and the same graphics card to render the resulting plots, so it is open to question how independent these processes really are. If it's not practical to include your actual input here, you at least need to provide an example that reproduces the behavior you observe. Relying on guesswork is not a good use of people's time.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.
OK, I understand. I will provide short version of my code. Till then `HoldAll` guys :)

Comment: @Szabolcs -- Wolfram advised me that a single v9 license now gives one access to 2 control kernels and 6 computing kernels (up from 4 in v8).  Just a point of information.  Everything else you mention has my total agreement.  We share an interest in using Mma for parallelizing jobs.  With regard to the OPs problem, I'd like to see it thought through here because if it isn't sooner or later I'll run into the same problem;-)

Answer (score 8):

This is more of a big comment not answer to your quesetion!

Here is a function I want to `Parallelize`. I have four cores in my machine so I `Launch` four kernels and distribute the definition of my functions to the kernels.

```
fun[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
Plot3D[Evaluate[Im[a ArcSin[(b x + I y)^c]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
Mesh -> None,PlotStyle ->Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.8]], 
ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red}, PlotPoints -> 120,MaxRecursion -> 4];
LaunchKernels[4];
DistributeDefinitions[fun]
```

> {fun}

Now do what you want to do

```
Parallelize[{fun[1, 1, 3], fun[1, 2, 4], fun[2, 1, 3], fun[3, 3, 3]}, 
Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

And the result is as expected!
[image]

My PC Config:

> Windows 7 64-bit (SP1)
>   /Core i7 620M Quad Core
>   /4 GB RAM

Tested:

> Mathematica 8.0.4
>   /Mathematica 9.0.1

Comment: +1 because I think what you've posted will really help point us in a better direction to solve the problem.  Could you post some of the same info I asked for in my comment on the original question.  It might help establish the differences between why yours works and the OPs doesn't

Comment: Thanks. Utilization now is about 30-68%, but it is not stable. 
Similarly with your code 60-70% (executed in 3.3s so maybe this is the reason).